# Ignoring non custom items during XML de-Serialization

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, xml-deserialization

I do a de-serialization of a XML file which is something like:

```
  <?xml version="1.1" ?>
  <Veggies>
       <Carrot>
             <quantity> 1 </quantity>
       </Carrot>
  </Veggies>
```

Ok. I write classes like

```
[Serializable]
public class Veggies
{
    [XmlRoot("Veggies")]
    public Carrot carrot;
}

[Serializable]
public class Carrot
{
   [XmlElement("Quantity")]
   public string Quantity;
}
```

All is well.

But if someone parses an input file which is something like below,

```
  <?xml version="1.1" ?>
  <Figs>
      <quantity> 11 </quantity>
  </Figs>
  <Veggies>
       <Carrot>
             <quantity> 1 </quantity>
       </Carrot>
  </Veggies>
```

I get an error.
Could you please suggest me a solution so that the Quantity of carrot can alone be retrieved leaving the other data but throwing no errors ?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe deserialisation is not what you want, but rather XML parser? That way you get to decide where everything goes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guyz.. I figured myself out!

```
<?xml version="1.1" ?>
<Figs>
  <quantity> 11 </quantity>
</Figs>
<Veggies>
    <Carrot>
          <quantity> 1 </quantity>
    </Carrot>
</Veggies>
```

is not allowed because it does not respect the rule that "All Elements should be inside the RootElement tag."

If the file had been something like,

```
<?xml version="1.1" ?>
<Veggies>
    <Figs>
        <quantity> 11 </quantity>
    </Figs>
    <Carrot>
        <quantity> 1 </quantity>
    </Carrot>
</Veggies>
```

Then the quantity of the carrot can alone be read and others don't exactly throw any errors.

So, "Always put the elements inside a rootElement (here in example, "Veggies")" or in other words, the elements should obey the de-serialization class structures.

Thanks.